# Make text that changes colors

Tags: html, text, colors

I want to make text that changes colors, like automatically, can anyone help me with that?
Like, color changing text that let's say
THIS MESSAGE
It will change every other second from every other letter being red/black.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Can you give some examples of what you tried already?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using jQuery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var y;

    setInterval(function () {
      if (y == 0) {
          $('.text').css('color','#ff0000');
          y = 1;
      } else {
          if (y = 1) {
            $('.text').css('color','#999');
              y = 0;
          }

      }
    }, 1000); // change the time if you want

    });


</script>
</head>
<body>
<span class="text">Change color text</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want but this jquery will automaticly change colours every second.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z0stj4cx/)

```
function randomcolor() {
    $('h1').each(function () {
        var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor((256)*Math.random())) + ',' + (Math.floor((256)*Math.random())) + ',' + (Math.floor((256)*Math.random())) + ')';
        $(this).css("color", hue);
    });
}
randomcolor();

setInterval(function(){randomcolor();}, 1000);
```

I hope this solves your problem!